# Multiple equality constraints in Matlab's optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, quadprog

I am sorry if this sounds like a newbie question! I am all brand new to Matlab and the optimization toolbox!

I have an optimization problem using quadprog, I have two equality constraints in my problem. Using the general formula:

`x = quadprog(H,f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,x0,options)`

but here I can only have Aeq and beq as equality constraints! A and b are inequality constraints...

Is it possible to have something like a set for the equality constraints? that is having multiple variables for equality in Aeq and beq in the form of a set or something? I have been looking and trying for a while with no luck!

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Aeq is in matrix form thereby allowing for a set of equalities.

Answer (score 0):

The equality constraints are given in matrix form `Aeq*x==beq`. Therefore, each row of `Aeq` can define a separate equation. For example, if you have three unknowns, and you want the sum of the first two to be equal to 2, and the difference of the second two (`x(3)-x(2)`) to be equal to 3, you write

```
Aeq = [1 1 0; 0 -1 1];
beq = [2;3];
```